# set OpenLayers.Map extent dynamically

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

```
    if (workspace=="x") {
        bbox = [3461431.90483,5555489.54044,3461896.81256,5555951.68634];
    } else 
    if (workspace=="y") {
        bbox = [471730.87469,5524059.31339 ,472552.36397,5524962.18860];
    }
...
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",{
      projection : new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466"),
      units : "m",
      maxResolution : 2,
      maxExtent : new OpenLayers.Bounds(bbox)
  });
```

I work on a gis client that makes use of OpenLayers / Geoserver. Since I use the same code for several maps, it would be very useful if I did not have to hard-code the bounding box of the respective map in javascript, but to retrieve the coordinates from the geoserver. Is this possible?

-_________________________________

I know that I can receive the bounding box via `GetCapabilities` as a huge XML File that I would have to parse, but there must be a shortcut.